# Go 1.1.1 and ODBC with MSSQL

Tags: odbc, go

Currently have **FreeTDS 0.92.4** / **unixODBC 2.3.1** up and running, connecting with a MSSQL server and able to execute queries etc.

I've found this list of ODBC implementations for Go, and have tried the two in bold:

- BenoyRNair https://github.com/BenoyRNair/godbc/
- Wei guangjing https://github.com/weigj/go-odbc
- **Mark Severson** https://bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc
- Luke Mauldin https://github.com/LukeMauldin/lodbc
- Robert Johnstone https://bitbucket.org/rj/odbc3-go/
- **brainman** http://code.google.com/p/odbc/

---

## mgodbc

I'm getting a bunch of deprecation warnings *(looking at the headers they're deprecated for OSX 10.8 and later)*:

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
mgodbc.go: In function 'mSQLColAttribute':
mgodbc.go:31: warning: 'SQLColAttributeW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:128)
mgodbc.go: At top level:
mgodbc.go:44: warning: 'SQLDisconnect' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:896)
mgodbc.go:51: warning: 'SQLGetDiagRecW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:233)
mgodbc.go:62: warning: 'SQLGetInfoW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:273)
mgodbc.go:67: warning: 'SQLBindParameter' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlext.h:2519)
mgodbc.go:70: warning: 'SQLDriverConnectW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:336)
mgodbc.go:73: warning: 'SQLSetEnvAttr' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:1120)
mgodbc.go:74: warning: 'SQLFreeHandle' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:942)
mgodbc.go:75: warning: 'SQLSetConnectAttrW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:245)
mgodbc.go:78: warning: 'SQLGetDiagFieldW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:223)
mgodbc.go:82: warning: 'SQLRowCount' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:1076)
mgodbc.go:98: warning: 'SQLGetData' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:975)
mgodbc.go:99: warning: 'SQLEndTran' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:902)
mgodbc.go:102: warning: 'SQLCloseCursor' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:831)
mgodbc.go:103: warning: 'SQLPrepareW' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlucode.h:239)
mgodbc.go:107: warning: 'SQLNumResultCols' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:1058)
mgodbc.go:113: warning: 'SQLAllocHandle' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:799)
mgodbc.go:114: warning: 'SQLExecute' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:921)
mgodbc.go:115: warning: 'SQLFetch' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sql.h:924)
mgodbc.go:119: warning: 'SQLNumParams' is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sqlext.h:2448)
```

#### Update

Following a suggestion from mac01021, from go-nuts irc, I've added

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
```

This gets rid of the deprecation warnings, but still doesn't build against the included iODBC of OS X

Replacing the above line with:

```
#cgo darwin CFLAGS: -I/opt/local/include
```

and voila, mgodbc builds now *(using the installed unixODBC)*
although now a nice little segfault occurs upon import =(

---

## odbc

I'm getting build errors:

```
# code.google.com/p/odbc/api
api/api.go:13: undefined: SQLSMALLINT  
api/api.go:14: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:15: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:19: undefined: SQLSMALLINT  
api/api.go:20: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:21: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:22: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:23: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:24: undefined: SQLUSMALLINT  
api/api.go:25: undefined: SQLUINTEGER  
api/api.go:25: too many errors
```

#### Update

Thanks @alex for the `cgo` info. I've modified `api_unix.go` with the below

```
// Copyright 2012 The Go Authors. All rights reserved.  
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style  
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.  

// +build linux darwin  
// +build cgo  

package api  

// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -lodbc  
// #cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -lodbc  
// #cgo darwin CFLAGS: -I /opt/local/include  
// #include <sql.h>  
// #include <sqlext.h>  
import "C"
```

The iODBC included with OS X has some things that are listed as deprecated *(and I've had better luck with unixODBC in the past)*

I've added the `-I /opt/local/include` to the CFLAGS to, hopefully, point to the unixODBC headers, and not the ones included by Apple (which have the deprecation warnings etc.)

Running `# go build -x` gives me:

```
WORK=/var/folders/z2/k9vxn7gn6395vb3y2qc7_1040000gn/T/go-build784364461  
mkdir -p $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/  
mkdir -p $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/  
cd /Users/jr/Development/go/src/code.google.com/p/odbc/api  
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -- -I /opt/local/include -I $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ api_unix.go  
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6c -F -V -w -I $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -I /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64 -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_defun.6 -D GOOS_darwin -D GOARCH_amd64 $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_defun.c  
gcc -I . -g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common -print-libgcc-file-name
gcc -I . -g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common -I /opt/local/include -I $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_main.o -c $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_main.c  
gcc -I . -g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common -I /opt/local/include -I $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_export.o -c $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_export.c  
gcc -I . -g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common -I /opt/local/include -I $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/api_unix.cgo2.o -c $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/api_unix.cgo2.c  
gcc -I . -g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_.o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_main.o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_export.o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/api_unix.cgo2.o -lodbc
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -dynimport $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_.o -dynout $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_import.c  
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6c -F -V -w -I $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/ -I /usr/local/go/pkg/darwin_amd64 -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_import.6 -D GOOS_darwin -D GOARCH_amd64 $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_import.c  
gcc -I . -g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-common -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_all.o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_export.o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/api_unix.cgo2.o -Wl,-r -nostdlib /usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64/libgcc.a  
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6g -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_go_.6 -p code.google.com/p/odbc/api -D _/Users/jr/Development/go/src/code.google.com/p/odbc/api -I $WORK ./api.go $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/api_unix.cgo1.go  
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/pack grcP $WORK $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api.a $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_go_.6 $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_import.6 $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_cgo_defun.6 $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/api/_obj/_all.o  
mkdir -p $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/_obj/  
mkdir -p $WORK/code.google.com/p/  
cd /Users/jr/Development/go/src/code.google.com/p/odbc  
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/6g -o $WORK/code.google.com/p/odbc/_obj/_go_.6 -p code.google.com/p/odbc -complete -D _/Users/jr/Development/go/src/code.google.com/p/odbc -I $WORK -I /Users/jr/Development/go/pkg/darwin_amd64 ./column.go ./conn.go ./driver.go ./error.go ./handle.go ./odbcstmt.go ./param.go ./result.go ./rows.go ./stats.go ./stmt.go ./tx.go  
# code.google.com/p/odbc  
./column.go:22: undefined: api.SQLGetData  
./column.go:28: undefined: api.SQLBindCol  
./column.go:47: undefined: api.SQLDescribeCol  
./conn.go:20: undefined: api.SQLAllocHandle  
./conn.go:28: undefined: api.SQLDriverConnect  
./conn.go:39: undefined: api.SQLDisconnect  
./driver.go:26: undefined: api.SQLAllocHandle  
./driver.go:34: undefined: api.SQLSetEnvAttr  
./driver.go:43: undefined: api.SQLSetEnvAttr  
./driver.go:50: undefined: api.SQLSetEnvAttr  
./driver.go:50: too many errors
```

It looks like the header path include is being passed correctly?
But still looks like things are not quite linking correctly?

*for `SQLGetData` I do see a matching definition from the `//sys  SQLGetData...` comment from `api.go` within `/opt/local/include/sql.h`*

---

## UPDATE

The library mentioned at the top:

> **brainman** http://code.google.com/p/odbc/

Now works as a go-gettable package on OSX. There's even documentation to get you started with the odbc/tds portions.

Comment: I've also built pyODBC against my installed unixODBC/FreeTDS libs and everything connects as it should (just trying to rule things out)

Comment: [Updating the iODBC installation](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Stable%20Version%203.52.12) seems like it makes more sense than shifting to a driver manager that was never blessed by Apple...  No deprecation markers in these header files, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows:

```
>go version
go version devel +edd229b63fa4 Wed Jun 26 11:36:18 2013 -0700 windows/amd64
>go get -v code.google.com/p/odbc
code.google.com/p/odbc (download)
code.google.com/p/odbc/api
code.google.com/p/odbc
>go get -v bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc
bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc (download)
bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc
>
```

On Linux:

```
$ go version
go version devel +65e2aba21abe Wed Jun 26 13:14:11 2013 -0700 linux/amd64
$ sudo apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unixodbc is already the newest version.
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
$ go get -v code.google.com/p/odbc
code.google.com/p/odbc (download)
code.google.com/p/odbc/api
code.google.com/p/odbc
$ go get -v bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc
bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc (download)
bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc
$
```

On Darwin, you seem to have issues with SQL header files.

```
/usr/include/sql.h
/usr/include/sqlext.h
/usr/include/sqltypes.h
/usr/include/sqlucode.h
```

Contact the odbc package authors to report these problems.

UPDATE:

When you tell us about the error

```
mgodbc.go:180: cannot convert &state[0] (type *uint16) to type *_Ctype_SQLWCHAR
```

you don't tell us what the type of _Ctype_SQLWCHAR is. We can only guess! My guess would be that it should look like this

```
package main

func main() {
    type _Ctype_ushort uint16
    type _Ctype_WCHAR _Ctype_ushort
    type _Ctype_SQLWCHAR _Ctype_WCHAR
    var state [6]uint16
    // (*C.SQLWCHAR)(&state[0])
    _ = (*_Ctype_SQLWCHAR)(&state[0])
}
```

which compiles with no errors.

UPDATE:

Use a systematic approach to problem solving.

Read about Go build contraints: [Build Constraints, Package build](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/).

Read the files in [code.google.com/p/odbc/api](https://code.google.com/p/odbc/source/browse/api/).

Grep the files in [code.google.com/p/odbc/api](https://code.google.com/p/odbc/source/browse/api/).

```
$ grep -r 'linux' *
api_unix.go:// +build linux
api_unix.go:// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -lodbc
Makefile:   GOOS=linux ./mksyscall_unix.pl $^ \
mksyscall_unix.pl:// +build linux
mksyscall_unix.pl:// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -lodbc
zapi_unix.go:// +build linux
zapi_unix.go:// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -lodbc
$
```

Clearly, after reading the `api_unix.go`, `zapi_unix.go`, `mksyscall_unix.pl`, and `Makefile` files, when the `api_unix.go` file is modified, the `zapi_unix.go` file should be modified too.

You probably didn't do that. Therefore, `darwin` is not included in the `zapi_unix.go` build constraints. The package `api` names that you show as undefined are defined in `zapi_unix.go`.

```
api.SQLGetData
api.SQLBindCol  
api.SQLDescribeCol  
api.SQLAllocHandle  
api.SQLDriverConnect  
api.SQLDisconnect  
api.SQLAllocHandle  
api.SQLSetEnvAttr
```

Comment: running `go get -v code.google.com/p/odbc give me the second error box from my question. My go version is 1.1.1 darwin/amd64

Comment: Thanks @peterSO. I was able to get this to build/install on a dev CentOS box just fine. Apple insists on including iODBC by default, sigh. I've installed unixODBC but the go build is referencing the header files of the default iODBC install, and not the headers provided by unixODBC. So I just need to have go look there during the install and I think it should work =)

Comment: Justin, code.google.com/p/odbc is not supported on darwin, because I don't have darwin. But, if you add darwin to lines like https://code.google.com/p/odbc/source/browse/api/api_unix.go#5 it might just work for you.

Comment: @alex: You should say which operating systems you support on your [odbc driver project](http://code.google.com/p/odbc/) site.

Comment: @Justin: I've revised my answer to reflect your recent update to your question.

Comment: @Justin: I've revised my answer to reflect your recent update to your question.

Comment: Thanks @peterSO, it looks like I was just missing the prior modifications, I had added in api_unix.go, in the other files, doh! The package builds now! Although I do get the same seg fault I get with mgodbc, so I've still got some work to do. Thanks for getting me on the right path =)

Comment: [Updating the iODBC installation](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/Downloads#Stable%20Version%203.52.12) seems like it makes more sense than shifting to a driver manager that was never blessed by Apple...  No deprecation markers in these header files, either.